# [OpenStack .NET API]: Is there a way to combine the Object creation and Container creation in one call?

Tags: openstack, rackspace-cloud, rackspace

Currently I do this

```
try
{
    cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerName, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName, 4096, FileMetaData);

}
catch (ItemNotFoundException ex1)
{
     try
     {
         cloudFilesProvider.CreateContainer(inStrContainerName);
         cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerName, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName, 4096, FileMetaData);
     }
     catch(Exception ex2)
     {
         return false;
     }
}
```

So essentially if the container does not exist then its 3 separate API calls.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simplify the code by reducing it to the following two lines.

```
cloudFilesProvider.CreateContainer(inStrContainerName);
cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile(inStrContainerName, inStrSrcFilePath, strDesFileName, 4096, FileMetaData);
```

`CreateContainer` is safe to call for a container that already exists. It returns `ContainerCreated` if the container is created, or `ContainerExists` if the container was not created because it already exists.

PS: The return values (with information like the above) for the `IObjectStorageProvider` methods will be well documented for release 1.2.0.0.

---

**Edit: To reduce the number of API calls your code makes, you could use a cache class like the following.** The `CreateIfNecessary` method attempts to create the container only if it is not previously known to exist. The `ClearCache` method provides a manual method for continuing to use the cache even if you delete a container.

*This code is currently untested.*

```
public class ContainerManager
{
    private readonly CloudFilesProvider _provider;
    private readonly string _region;
    private readonly bool _useInternalUrl;
    private readonly CloudIdentity _identity;

    private readonly HashSet<string> _containers = new HashSet<string>();

    public ContainerManager(CloudFilesProvider provider, string region, bool useInternalUrl, CloudIdentity identity)
    {
        if (provider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");

        _provider = provider;
        _region = region;
        _useInternalUrl = useInternalUrl;
        _identity = identity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the cache of known containers.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <alert class="warning">
    /// If a container was deleted after this cache was in use, this method must be called or
    /// <see cref="CreateIfNecessary(string)"/> could fail to create a container which does not
    /// exist.
    /// </alert>
    /// </remarks>
    public void ClearCache()
    {
        lock (_containers)
        {
            _containers.Clear();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures that a container exists in the Cloud Files store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// <alert class="warning">
    /// If a container was deleted after this cache was in use, and <see cref="ClearCache()"/>
    /// has not been called, this method could fail to create a container which does not exist.
    /// </alert>
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="container">The name of the container to create.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">If <paramref name="container"/> is <c>null</c>.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">If <paramref name="container"/> is empty.</exception>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the container was created; otherwise <c>false</c> if the container already existed.</returns>
    public bool CreateIfNecessary(string container)
    {
        if (container == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(container))
            throw new ArgumentException("container cannot be empty");

        // don't try to create the same container multiple times
        if (_containers.Contains(container))
            return false;

        ObjectStore result = _provider.CreateContainer(container, _region, _useInternalUrl, _identity);
        if (result == ObjectStore.ContainerCreated || result == ObjectStore.ContainerExists)
        {
            lock (_containers)
            {
                // add to _containers even if the result is ContainerExists, because that
                // means it simply wasn't known to this cache.
                _containers.Add(container);
            }
        }

        // only return true if the container was actually created
        return result == ObjectStore.ContainerCreated;
    }
}
```

Comment: usually there is gonna be lot more objects than containers(atleast in my case). So if i use cloudFilesProvider.CreateContainer and cloudFilesProvider.CreateObjectFromFile every time i wanna store an object in cloudfiles that just doubles the number of requests, in which case the code i have will result in lesser number of requests on the longer run. What i was essentially looking for is to see if there was a method that made just one request which does both the container create if it doesn't exist and then create the object.
-Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with an example `ContainerManager` cache that you can use to avoid making multiple calls to `CreateContainer`.

Comment: So this works for me in one case where am creating multiple containers withing the life cycle of an object of 'ContainerManager'. But in a case where i'm uploading files from multiple clients utilities restarted everyday then i'm guessing the cache '_containers' is recreated every time the utility is restarted right?

Comment: That's correct, however in either scenario it will reduce the number of API calls to a minimum so you shouldn't run into problems with the strategy.